# "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED": Cloudflare + Openshift + NameCheap

Tags: dns, openshift, mean-stack, cloudflare

My configuration is as follows:

1. **NameCheap** has Cloudflare nameservers only.
2. **Openshift** has domain alias changed from *app-account.rhcloud.com* to *domain.com*.
3. **CloudFlare DNS settings** has no A records, but two CNAME records: `domain.com is an alias of app-account.rhcloud.com` and `www is an alias of domain.com`.
4. **CloudFlare Page Rules** forward `http://www.domain.com/*` to `http://domain.com/$1`

These were all configured based on the solutions found online that have worked for others.  My domain.com is accessible without issue, but www.domain.com provides this error:

[image]

I'm obviously missing something.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just FYI: you can have more than one alias even on free plan with OpenShift. Just go to alias list of you app and you can add another alias - url is: https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application/xxxxx-yourapp/aliases

[image]

Comment: Well, damn, I wish they had made that clearer.  If you only used one alias, that link just says "Change Alias".  Thanks for the info.  Now I don't need to waste a gear on the alias :)

Answer (score 0):

> Update: **I stand corrected. See the chosen answer for the use of aliases which is a much better solution.**

It seems the fix for this was rather simple.  The problem was that the `www.domain.com` needs exist in OpenShift.  Because my account is the free tier, OpenShift did not provide me an option to add another domain.

To mimic that, in OpenShift I added another application: PHP 5.4 with the domain alias `www.domain.com` replacing `app-route-account.rhcloud.com`.

Then in CloudFlare, I changed `www is an alias of domain.com` to `www is an alias of app-route-account.rhcloud.com`.

And, all is well. :)

If I was using a premium OpenShift account, I could have just added another domain to the first application, as `www.domain.com`. I hope this can help someone.